# AWS API Gateway - Issues in setting up cross-account access

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use an existing API gateway which is present in `accountA`. I am having some EC2 instances which are having some scripts to invoke the API gateway present. These instances may/may not reside in the same AWS account as the one where my API gateway is present (Let's call the other account as `accountB`).

For the authentication part currently, there's only `AWS_IAM` authentication implemented at the API gateway level. The EC2 instances (in both the accounts) are having IAM roles attached which are having IAM permissions to invoke the API.

The permission for the same looks as:

```
{
            "Sid": "InvokeAPI",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "*"
}
```

When I try to invoke the API from the instances which are in `accountA`, it is working as expected. However, when I try to invoke the API from my instances in `accountB`, the gateway returns a 403 error with the following message:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::accountB:assumed-role/invoke_api_iam_role/i-xxxxxxxxx is not authorized to access this resource
```

I tried to look at [API gateway resource policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html) and tried to whitelist the `accountB`'s EC2 IAM role in `accountA` API Gateway's resource policy and still, I'm getting the same error.

Current resource policy implemented at the API gateway kinda looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountB:role/invoke_api_iam_role"
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:accountA:myAPIID/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

For signing the requests to the API gateway through the awsv4 signature, I use [aws-requests-auth](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth)

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turns out, everything above is correct and you need to deploy the API to a particular stage for applying the resource policy against it.